# Mysql doesn't validate date field properly?

Tags: mysql

### **UPDATE2:** Please don't correct statement the statement. Read question carefully!

I already new that the statement below is wrong. Please read the question properly!

Following query I noticed is working with MySql, where I expected an error or empty data due to  wrong formatting -

```
select * from test where date='"2014-11-24';
```

Instead MySql is giving output for `date=''`. Is it expected or a bug?

I expected to give a syntax error(**"** not ended), or no data (searching whole date i.e. `"2014-11-24` which won't exists).

**UPDATE1**: Guys, I know I have error in the syntax, and no It is not giving an empty row. I have some rows with date as empty(not null), like date=''. **I am getting these entries as result!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'"2014-11-24'
 ^
```

Is an invalid date. But the syntax has no issues therefore it computes to become a non existant date and then returns you result where there is no date, i.e. null.

```
'2014-11-24'
```

Is valid

This can also be confirmed with the following test

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-11-24')    // valid value is returned
```

VS

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('"2014-11-24')    // 0 is returned because the date was invalid
```

**Edit**

Ok, seems like its still not clear for you. Take this example it will remove the confusion

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP("")  // Empty string right? guess what; returns 0
```

That means for an invalid date the value computes to be 0, for an empty date it computes to be 0, for null it computes to be 0. `0=0=0` :) That is why you see the results where the date is empty in your table when you go for an invalid date.

Comment: Ah! I got it, so every non existant date, like '8he82e28', '', '"2014-11-24' they all evaluate to 0. SO they all are treated as same dates by mysql!

Thank you for the answer. It is the clear now. However I would have liked MySql to give invalid date format error. It would have been safer way to prevent coding errors like the one I made.

Comment: Nope its not a syntax error, its just an invalid value. For example if you put a number inside quotes does that make it a syntax error? Nope :) Your syntax is fine, value isn't.

Comment: So mysql checks only suntax and does not validate values. This is something new I learned.

Comment: That's correct. Almost every language does that on a basic level. We have to put in something more to ensure data integrity

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of double quote(") in your query?

```
'"2014-11-24'
 ^
```

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date = '2014-11-24';
```

Answer (score 0):

The query searches for `"2014-11-24` value in the `test` table. The record belongs to `"2014-11-24` value won't be existed in the test table and hence empty value is returned.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE Date = '2014-11-21'
```